# Having trouble with image preload code

Tags: javascript

I have this object constructor function that has a preload method for preloading
rollover images pairs.

So, I have two questions:

1: why is the alert dialog just doing 'STR: ' with no data attached? (this type of problem is generally due to my blindness.

2: is it possible to treat the this.buttons_on and this.buttons_off as objects in that instead of

a numerical index, use a sting index so the rollover event handler does not need to loop through
the buttons_on and buttons_off arrays to get the one that should be swapped out;

```
function _NAV()
     {
      this.list_off = [];
      this.list_on = [];
      this.buttons_on = [];
      this.buttons_off = [];
      this.buttons_all = {}; // .on and .off
      this.button_events = {};
      this.img = true;
      this.img_ids = {}
      this.preLoad = function()
                   {
                    if(document.images)  //creates image object array for preload.
                      {
                       var STR = '';
                       for(var i = 0; i < list_off.length; i++)
                          {
                           var lab_on = list_on[i].replace('\.jpg', '');
                           var lab_off = list_off[i].replace('\.jpg', '');
                           STR += lab_on+'||'+lab_off+"\n";
                           this.buttons_on[i] = new Image();
                           this.buttons_on[i].src = srcPath+list_on[i];
                           this.bottons_on[i].id = img_ids[i];
                           this.buttons_off[i] = new Image();
                           this.buttons_off[i].src = srcPath+list_off[i];
                           this.buttons_off[i].id = img_ids[i];
                          }
                       alert("STR: "+STR);
                      }
                    else
                      {
                       this.img = false
                      }
                   }
      //// ...etc...
```

Here is the call before the onload event fires

```
  var rollover = new _NAV();
  rollover.preLoad();
```

Here are the arrays used

```
 var srcPath = '../nav_buttons/';
 var list_off = new Array(); // not new Object;
 list_off[0] = "bio_off.jpg";
 list_off[1] = "cd_off.jpg";
 list_off[2] = "home_off.jpg";
 list_off[3] = "inst_off.jpg";
 list_off[4] = "photo_off.jpg";
 list_off[5] = "rev_off.jpg";
 list_off[6] = "samp_off.jpg";


 var list_on = new Array();
 list_on[0] = "bio_on.jpg";
 list_on[1] = "cd_on.jpg";
 list_on[2] = "home_on.jpg";
 list_on[3] = "inst_on.jpg";
 list_on[4] = "photo_on.jpg";
 list_on[5] = "rev_on.jpg";
 list_on[6] = "samp_on.jpg";

 var img_ids = new Array();
```

Thanks for time and attention.

Comment: `list_on[i]`? Think about it. Should be `this.list_on[i]`, but when did you put anything in that Array?

Answer (score 0):

## 1:

Try PHPGlue's suggestion and add `this.` in front of all your member variables (`this.list_on`, `this.list_off`, `this.img_ids`)

You also have a typo on one line. `bottons_on` is misspelled.

```
this.bottons_on[i].id = img_ids[i];
```

## 2:

Yes, you can use a string as an index. Just make `buttons_on` and `buttons_off` objects instead of arrays.

```
function _NAV()
{
    this.buttons_on = {};
    this.buttons_off = {};
    // For example:
    this.buttons_off[lab_off] = new Image();
}
```